# Time handling with timestamp and offset

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I'm creating a **custom data type** that needs to store a **set of exact timestamps** (to millisecond accuracy) in a way that is both efficient and correct. I'm not particularly famiilar with the intricacies of timestamp handling so thought I would ask here for some wise advice.

I can see many options:

- Store a Joda `Instant` for every timestamp.
- Store a Joda `DateTime` for every timestamp.
- Store a single Joda `DateTime` object once for the data type, and have a `long` offset for all the other timestamps relative to the main `DateTime`
- Express every timestamp as a `long` offset to a fixed point (e.g. the Unix epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z )
- .....other combinations.....

Questions:

- What is the best way to store a sequence of timestamps?
- What are the key tradeoffs?
- Any pitfalls to watch out for?

Comment: Is your custom class defining an interval? If so, you may want to consider just using the Joda Time [Interval class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_interval.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your storage options makes sense, and it's nice to see all of your options are with actual instants and never local datetimes (e.g., without time zones).

Your custom class will really be defined by its interface, so if you choose to *store* longs (epoch offsets) you can always provide interface methods to get the values from the sequence (and I assume other things like "deltas" -- or intervals, durations, or periods in Joda-speak) in human readable datetimes and periods if you like.

As you asked a number of questions, involving trade-offs, here's what I can offer:

- Storing a sequence of longs is the most space-efficient.
- Longs are not really as bad as you might think, since if your interface methods want to return datetimes, you just pass the long to the DateTime constructor.
- Instants are thin wrappers over longs and provide convenience methods if you need to add durations to them or compute durations from instants; your code might look a little nicer than if you do your own math on longs and then construct a DateTime or Period or Duration around them.
- DateTimes are great if you don't have excessive storage requirements and the actual date and time-of-day matter to the clients of your custom data type.  Will your users care that a timestamp is on October 10th at 16:22 in the America/Los Angeles time zone?  Or is the duration between the timestamps all that matter?
- Storing a datetime or instant plus an array of offsets looks like a messy implementation since there are two concepts in play.  I would think storing a single sequence of instants/datetimes only, and not mixing in durations, make a lot more sense.  If you need to work with durations, just compute them in your interface methods.

I would say the only pitfalls to watch out for involve dealing with time zones if you are storing longs and your clients need to be thinking in datetimes.

In terms of tradeoffs, I only really see that longs, being primitive, save space, and I would guess a miniscule amount of time since DateTimes are objects and there is all that heap allocation and deallocation that takes place.  But again, unless you are severely memory-constrained, I would say the best thing is to store DateTimes.  Joda-Time can do all the time zone management for you.  The parsing and formatting routines are easy and thread-safe.  There are tons of convenience methods in place.  And you won't have to do any conversion of your own from datetimes to longs.  Storing longs only feels like a premature optimzation to me.  Strangely enough, FWIW, I would probably do that in Python, since Python's datetime objects are naive, rather than timezone-aware, by default!  Jada-Time makes IMHO a very nice and easy to understand distinction between Instants and Local DateTimes, so sticking with DateTimes everywhere will be, I believe, your best bet.

Comment: thanks for a great answer - it both confirmed some of my suspicions and taught me some new things.